# I am getting an error " failed to fetch...." forbidden IP

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, updates, python

I am getting this error when attempting to install software, or upgrade my system after a sudo-apt-get update. I have searched it, and many say it happens when your dist. is at its "end of life", but I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. So my dist shouldnt be at its end of life.

```
sts... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libexpat1-dev libpython3-dev libpython3.5-dev python-pip-whl python3-dev
  python3-setuptools python3-wheel python3.5-dev
Suggested packages:
  python-setuptools-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libexpat1-dev libpython3-dev libpython3.5-dev python-pip-whl python3-dev python3-pip
  python3-setuptools python3-wheel python3.5-dev
0 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,219 kB/39.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 57.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Ign:1 http://ubuntu.uberglobalmirror.com/archive xenial-updates/universe i386 python-pip-whl all 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4
Ign:2 http://ubuntu.uberglobalmirror.com/archive xenial-updates/universe i386 python3-pip all 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4
Err:1 http://ubuntu.uberglobalmirror.com/archive xenial-updates/universe i386 python-pip-whl all 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.124.241.168 80]
Err:2 http://ubuntu.uberglobalmirror.com/archive xenial-updates/universe i386 python3-pip all 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4
  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.124.241.168 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.uberglobalmirror.com/archive/pool/universe/p/python-pip/python-pip-whl_8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4_all.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.124.241.168 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.uberglobalmirror.com/archive/pool/universe/p/python-pip/python3-pip_8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4_all.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.124.241.168 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Change your mirror and try.

Comment: @ArijitChatterjee Changing the mirror produces the same result

Comment: Can't you open http://ubuntu.uberglobalmirror.com/archive xenial-updates/universe i386 in your browser? Is your internet working?

Comment: Try the Ubuntu Main Server; Check the nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: @ArijitChatterjee Yes I was able to open it, up to ...updates/universe, but there is not directory labeled "i386"

Comment: where did you get that i386 part initially? Was it in the auto generated sources.list?

Comment: Try to copy the required to your sources list from this link https://gist.github.com/rohitrawat/60a04e6ebe4a9ec1203eac3a11d4afc1 and forget the i386 thing. I never had such tags.

Comment: @ArijitChatterjee Thank you! that solved my problem. I have no Idea how or why my sources.list got so messed up.

Comment: Glad it worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My sources list was messed up. To fix everything, I replaced my currecnt "/etc//apt/sources.list"
with the default found here https://gist.github.com/rohitrawat/60a04e6ebe4a9ec1203eac3a11d4afc1

Answer (score 0):

A bad package repository can mess up your future installations. Go to /etc/apt/ folder and remove lists that are giving forbidden IP message.
I was having node but unable to update it because of a messy repository jonathon or so.
Removed it and flood gates for upgrade opened up.